# immunity debugger MSVCR90.dll R6034

Tags: debugging, debuggers, immunity-debugger, disassemblers

I'm new to the science of reverse engineering. I recently downloaded ***immunity debugger 1.85 32bit Assembler-Level Debugger***. My host machine is ***Windows 7 64 bit***. I have ***python 2.7 installed as 32 bit image*** and ***MSVCR90.dll*** in pythons install directory. Whenever I execute the pycommands I get a MSCVR90.dll runtime error R6034. Does this debugger work on 64 bit host? If so what can I do to correct this runtime error?

Your advice is really appreciated...

Comment: This can be due to side-by-side loading of the DLL. You can check the manifest of the executable to see if it references the **MSVCR90.dll** in there.

Comment: @tmr232 I did not see a manifest on the executable path of immunity. However Python had one that references MSVCR90.dll

Comment: I am not familiar with Immunity debugger and pycommands. So I'll ask - is Python embedded into Immunity? And are there any other compiled python modules involved?

Comment: Honestly I'm new to immunity and I'm not sure if Python is embedded. Immunity used Python very extensively.

Comment: In some cases, `python.dll` requires a specific CRT, but does not specify it in it's manifest. If the `*.pyd`s it loads need it as well, it might cause issues.

Comment: I think you're on to something. I temporarily renamed the manifest and msvcr90.dll. Now when I run the debugger I'm not getting any runtime errors. I'm going to trace the run with procmon to see if the runtime is being loaded from elsewhere.

Comment: I had a hack to solve a similar issue a while ago, maybe it will help - https://github.com/zeromq/pyzmq/issues/161#issuecomment-66776901

Comment: Also, the `sxstrace` command might come in handy.

Comment: Strange enough sxstrace did not show any information.